# mod_rewrite allow percentage sign in url

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\/\-\_]+)+$ .?p=$1 [L]
```

But if I have % sign in url, it won't work. How do I modify this rule to work with percentage sign?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the % to your [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[…]`). A character class specifies a group of characters that will be successful matches.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9/_%-]+)$ .?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Okei, but it seems that modrewrite is buggy, it wont go trough with %23, which is # in urlencode